# Firestore vuejs chained calls stop

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

I've been studying the tutorial on https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase. The following piece of code was not properly working for me.

```
signup() {
    fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password).then(user => {
        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)

        // create user obj
        fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
            name: this.signupForm.name,
            title: this.signupForm.title
        }).then(() => {
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
            this.$router.push('/dashboard')
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Could anyone help me?

P.S: After lots of research, I've stumbled upon that by this way I got the document created but the code inside then is not working yet. This change was based on Doug Stevenson's video on youtube about promises.

```
        const promise = fb.usersCollection.doc(user.user.uid).set({
          name: this.signupForm.name,
          title: this.signupForm.title
        })
        return promise.then(() => {
          console.log('set ok')
          this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
          this.performingRequest = false
          this.$router.push('/dashboard')
        }).catch(err => {
          this.performingRequest = false
          console.log(err)
          this.errorMsg = err.message
        })
```

P.S 2: The line of code below helps to get the document created:

```
firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true })
```

Comment: Please be more specific on why is not working. Are there errors? what happens and what you expected to happen? Also, why so many returns instead of chaining the `then` directly?

Comment: Dear Happy-Monad I notice that the code: `console.log('set ok')
this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile') this.$router.push('/dashboard')
this.performingRequest = false` does not run until another firebase function is called. There are no errors. The tutorial I'm studying does not have this amount of returns. I've modified after watch Doug Stevenson's video about Promises. After this I got the document created (doc.set) but the code isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

[Tylerhan](https://github.com/tylerhahn) has answered the question on [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3146). Here is the solution:

```
async signup () {
  this.performingRequest = true
  await fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password).then(user => {
    this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user.user)
  })
  const user = this.$store.getters.getCurrentUser
  const userProfile = {
    name: this.signupForm.name,
    title: this.signupForm.title
  }
  fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set(userProfile).then(() => {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
    this.performingRequest = false
    this.$router.push('/dashboard')
  }).catch(err => {
    this.performingRequest = false
    console.log(err)
    this.errorMsg = err.message
  })
}
```

Comment: FYI, the reason why the savvy tutorial has an error is the following: With version 5.0.0 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK (released on May 8, 2018), the return type signature for `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` has changed: it returns a promise that resolves with a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) while it used to return a `User` in the previous version, see https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about what is happening with the tutorial.